# What is the benefit & target of using ROS?

Tags: gazebo, catkin, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I control and access to my robot using ROS, or ROS is a simulating program only.
If I can control my robot ,, can you give me steps to start controlling it (I had done my mechanical design)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67434/what-is-the-benefit-&-target-of-using-ros?/) by [ahmed.shamroukh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5253/ahmed.shamroukh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Yes, ROS can be used to control robots.
2. ROS also includes packages for simulation.

See http://answers.ros.org/question/61939/why-use-ros/ and http://answers.ros.org/question/33811/why-choose-ros/ for some more information about what ROS can do / can be used for.

As first steps, I'd suggest to head over to [ros.org](http://www.ros.org) and have a look at the tutorials and projects.

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6